# fontlibrary.org fonts, Print Preview, and strong/em not rendering as bold/italic

Tags: css, pdf, printing, fonts, font-family

I'm trying to use fontlibrary.org to load fonts to produce documents as PDF. I currently use these same fonts on web sites and everything works as expected; however, when I try to print a document with these fonts, `strong` does not render bold and `em` does not render as italic. To work around this problem, I have to do this (this is already `sass`, so you can imagine the corresponding CSS):

```
  body {
    font-family: "HkGroteskRegular", sans-serif;
    strong {
      font-family: "HankenGroteskBold", sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    em {
      font-family: "HankenGroteskItalic", sans-serif;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  }

  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "NormungRegular", serif;
    strong {
      font-family: "NormungBold", serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    em {
      font-family: "NormungItalic", serif;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  }

  code, pre {
    font-family: 'FantasqueSansMonoRegular', monospace;
    strong {
      font-family: "FantasqueSansMonoBold", monospace;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    em {
      font-family: "FantasqueSansMonoItalic", monospace;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  }
```

So that leaves me with a few questions:

- <del>How does this work at all on the web? How does the browser load the bold font for bold, the italic font for italics, and so on?</del> Evidently, the browser simulates font variants for bold and italic, so it doesn't use the imported font variants.
- Since this doesn't work for print, who's broken? Does fontlibrary.org serve the fonts incorrectly and the browser (and `wkhtmltopdf`) can't find them? Do both the browser and `wkhtmltopdf` load the font files incorrectly?
- <del>If fontlibrary.org is broken</del> Since fontlibrary.org seems to use a font variant naming scheme that doesn't match what the rest of the world seems to except, then whom can I trust to serve these `@font-face` rules correctly? Do I have to write them myself to be sure?
- Is there anything I can do to make this work better?

**UPDATE: 2018-10-14**. I have noticed that when I download the fonts so that they can be found locally, everything works. I *suspect* that this happens because the locally-installed font names follow a naming convention for the font variants that allows the browser, Print Preview, and `pandoc` to find them. **I would really appreciate it if a few people would confirm that the naming convention solves the problem.** In that case, I could tweak the `@font-face` rules to load the fonts from fontlibrary.org so that I don't *need* to install the fonts locally.

Comment: the browser may be applying faux bold and faux italic, if you look closely you may see a difference. How you are doing the css for print is required as the basic set up, I'm lucky and the other half does this for me.

Comment: @CarolMcKay Indeed so, apparently. I just noticed the faux bold/italic this morning. Everything seems to work as expected when I install the font locally, and I imagine that some kind naming convention for the font variants makes it all work. That would explain why the fontlibrary fonts, which don't use the same naming convention, don't behave as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is a result of how Fontlibrary shares their fonts. If you look at the file https://fontlibrary.org/face/hk-grotesk (which is the link containing the font face css) at the very bottom you will see a section marked "The following rules are deprecated."
If you use the font names from that section (i.e. "Hanken Grotesk") and not the special names (like "HankenGroteskBold"), then web browsers seem to find the correct bold & italic forms. It's only using these special names that I find trouble (in my case with the Libertinus fonts).
Unfortunately, as these names are marked "deprecated", I don't know how long they will stay working. Nor, do I know why Fontlibrary setup this naming convention, which makes it more difficult to use the fonts than is necessary (in my opinion).